# Defining a real number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

No answers, please, hints only.
I want to express every nonzero $x\in \mathbb R$ as a product of two numbers that are not rational.

My attempt is $x=(a_1+b_1i)(a_2+b_2i)$ where $a_1, b_2\in \mathbb R$

Am I correct or do I need a hint?

Comment: I don't see how the result is $x$, or how it is real.

Comment: Start with a concrete example: how will you express $17$ as a product of two irrational numbers? What about $\pi$?

Comment: You really don't need to go to complex numbers for this.

Comment: Useful facts include: 1. multiplying two rational numbers gives you a rational number 2. multiplying a rational number by an irrational number gives you an irrational number.

Comment: Well if $x$ is not rational than $\sqrt{|x|}$ is not rational.   If $x$ is rational, then $\sqrt 2\times x$ is not rational.

Comment: if $x = (a_1 +b_1i)(a_2 + b_2i)$ the what are $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2$?  And how will you do this for some *other* real $w$ when $w \ne x$?  I don't think you actually understand what the question is asking.

Comment: By the way $(a_1 + b_1i)(a_2 + b_2i) = (a_1a_2-b_1b_2)  + 2(a_1b_2 + a_2b_1) i$ so $x =(a_1 + b_1i)(a_2 + b_2i) $ if and only if $a_1a_2 -b_1b_2 = x$ and $a_1b_2 + a_2b_1=0$.  How would be find these values of $a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2$ and how will you make sure that they are not rational.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- Why is addressing the case with positive $x\ne1$ the hard part?
- For such $x$, consider rational and irrational $x$ separately, and think about how $n$th roots would help.

Comment: With 1 is easy because I can write $1=(i)(-i)$. With every other value I have to include some real part to cancel out the irrationals and leave only a rational remaining.

I think I'm getting close to generalizing it

Comment: @Lex_i Is your heart still set on a complex factorization rather than a real one? If so, do you know about complex conjugates?

Comment: Yes, I know the conjugate of $a+bi$ is $a-bi$. I'm not set on complex factorization anymore though, now that I know it's not necessary.

Comment: $i$ and $-i$ are not irrational.

Comment: What the definition of irrational.  Babar the elephant is not a rational number.  Does that mean Babar the elephant is *ir*rational?  (Forget about complex numbers; that's just confusing things, it misses the point, and its leading you of on the wrong track.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Play with examples.

- $2=\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}$
- $-4=\frac{-4}{\sqrt{3}}\cdot \sqrt{3}$.
- $\frac{7}{5}=\sqrt{\frac{7}{5}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{7}{5}}$
- $\sqrt{2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot 2\sqrt{2}$
- etc.

Now generalize...

Answer (score 1):

How many ways are there to express $x=ab$ as product of two reals? How many of these ways have rational $a$? How many have rational $b$?

---

More constructively: Can you achieve $a=\sqrt 2$? Can you achieve $a=\sqrt 3$? Could it happen that $b$ is rational in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

- If $\frac{x}{\sqrt 2}$ is irrational we are done;
- If $\frac{x}{\sqrt 2}$ is rational. Let $x = \sqrt 2 \cdot \frac mn$ where $\gcd(m,n)=1$, and $$y = \frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt{4n^2+4n-1}}, z = \frac{m}{n}\cdot \sqrt{4n^2+4n-1} $$ Then $x=yz$ where $y$, $z$ are both irrational. In fact $4n^2+4n-1$ can be replaced with any non-square integer coprime to both $2$ and $n$, for example any prime number greater than both $n$ and $2$.

Comment: So then I can just generalize any $x$ as $\cfrac{x}{k}\cdot k$ for some irrational $k$?

Comment: @Lex_i Yes you can. Some irrational $k$'s are easier to deal with than others.

Comment: Wat if $\frac x{\sqrt 2}$ is *rational*?

Comment: @fleablood See my update please.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of cardinality might help.

For a given $x$ consider all then $w \in \mathbb R$ so that $w \ne 0$.

Only a countable number of $w$ will give us $\frac xw$ is rational, and an uncountable number of $w$ will give us $\frac xw$ is irrational.  And only a countable number of $w$ are rational and an uncountable number of $w$.  So there are an uncountable number of $w$ that are irrational and and have $\frac xw$ are irrational.

So just pick one of those.  Then $w$ is irrational and $\frac xw$ is irrational and $x = \frac xw\cdot w$.

So we know it *can* always be done.  But how to do it?

Well, if $x$ is rational, then we can pick $w$ be any irrational, say $w=\pi$.  Then $\pi$ is irrational, and $\frac x{\pi}$ is irrational, and $\pi\cdot \frac x\pi = x$.

ANd if $x$ is irrational.... well either $\frac x\pi$ is rational or irrational.  If $\frac x\pi = q\in \mathbb Q$ then $x = \pi*q$.  So we need to pick an irrational $w$ so that $\frac xw = \frac {\pi *q}{w}$ is irrational.

Well there are an uncountable number of irrational $w$ so that $\frac \pi w$ is irrational.  Can we come up with one?  Well $\sqrt \pi$ is irrational and $\frac {\pi}{\sqrt \pi} = \sqrt \pi$ is irrational.

So

If $\frac x{\pi}\not \in \mathbb Q$ let $w = \frac x{\pi}$ and $\pi \cdot \frac x{\pi} = x$.

If $\frac x{\pi} \in \mathbb Q$ then $\frac x{\sqrt{\pi}}\not \in \mathbb Q$.  Then $\sqrt \pi\cdot \frac x{\sqrt \pi} = x$.

That'll do it.